# How to Find Prime Number

Tags: syntax, python-3.6

How to find prime numbers?
Prime numbers are the numbers that are bigger than one, and are divisible only by themselves and one. One way to determine whether or not a number is a prime number is as follows:

->if the number < 2, then return False

->if the number is 2, then return True
->for each value of i, where i >=2 and i < number:
    if the number is divisible by i, then return False
->return True

My current code:

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number == 2:
        return True
    elif number < 2:
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(2, number):
            if number % i == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
def main():
    print(is_prmie(1))
    print(is_prmie(4))
    print(is_prmie(7))
```

Some syntax problems I don't know how to solve.
Can someone please help?
Thanks TA!

Comment: Small optimization, you can stop at `sqrt(number)` (make sure to pre-compute it since it's a slow operation). For example: `100 = 50 *2`, but you would have already checked `2` long before you got to `50`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find prime number to sortest loop condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973057/find-prime-number-to-sortest-loop-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    return False

  if x % 2 == 0:
    return x == 2

  i = 3
  while i <= sqrt(x):
    if x % i == 0:
      return False
    i += 2

  return True
```

Things to note:

- The only even prime is 2. The loop is restricted to odd numbers.
- Only factors up to and including the square root must be tested. Because if x = y * z and y ≥ sqrt(x) then z ≤ sqrt(x)
- Only one return statement in the loop. You can exit early on a non prime, but you must complete the loop to be sure the number is prime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `main()` and write `is_prime()` correctly.

```
def is_prime(number):
if number == 2:
    return True
elif number < 2:
    return False
else:
    for i in range(2, number):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
def main():
    print(is_prime(1))
    print(is_prime(4))
    print(is_prime(7))
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Spelling of is_prime at the time of method call is wrong. Also, you haven't mke a call to the method main at the end.

Small improvement:

```
for i in range(2, number):
```

this line can be as below as we don't need to check divisibility of the number after its half:

```
for i in range(2, (number/2)):
```

e.g. for checking 24 is prime or not, we need to check only upto 12 because it will never be divisible by number greater than 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php

        // PHP code to check wether a number is prime or Not 
        // function to check the number is Prime or Not 
        function primeCheck($number){ 

            if ($number == 1 || $number == 2 || $number % 2 !== 0) {
                 echo "Prime"; 
            }

            else if ($number % 2 == 0) 
            {
                echo "Not Prime"; 
            }
          } 

        echo primeCheck(5);
```